# Find the center-coordinates of a rotated rectangle

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I am having trouble with finding the X and Y-coordinates of the center of a rotated rectangle through mathematical calculations.
What I have is the width 'A' and height 'B' of a rectangle, as well as its rotation 'R' in degrees.
What would be the formula to calculate those points?
Here is a sketch to further explain what i am trying to do:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Depends on how you are rotating the `<div>`? `<canvas>`? This is JavaScript...and there's more than one way to *"skin a cat"*. CSS as well.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, I am only interested in the mathematical formula, not anything jsvascript related. Added the javascript tag by mistake..

Comment: Your question is quite confuse. On one hand you ask for the coordinates of the center of the rectangle (most probably the rotation center, so it does not move), and on the other you want to calculate "those points" !?

Comment: And if all you know is A, B, R, it is completely impossible to find the rectangle position.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I also know the coordinates of the left-uppermost corner of the square, forgot to mention that sorry

Comment: What is the left-uppermost ?? There is a leftmost and an uppermost, and they differ.

Comment: In the case shown by the picture, it is the leftmost point I have the coords of. It is always that point/corner of which i have the coordinates, it doesnt change. Maybe I didnt describe that well.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do it in pure way, by your self
it think this answer would be great for you
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270194/how-to-find-the-vertices-angle-after-rotation

if you want to use a package for this, then I do recommend
*flatten-js* , *geometric*  ,*Ecluid.ts*

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that the link you provided does the opposite: Calculate the corner points with the rotation of the center one. I am trying to achieve the opposite.

Comment: in the accepted answer, there is an explanation of how to find any point, not only the corner

Comment: for your situation, the center point is (a/2 + dx, b/2 +dy) "before rotate", so with the accepted answer you could calculate it after the rotation in respect of other point with a specific angle

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is what you are after, but here is a solution to a possibly related question.

We assume that the leftmost corner lies on the Y axis, and the bottommost on the X axis. Thus, the coordinates of these corners are `(0, B sin R)` and `(B cos R, 0)` respectively. The midpoint of the bottom side is `(B/2 cos R, B/2 sin R)`. To this we add a vector of length `A/2` in the orthogonal direction and obtain the coordinates of the center:

```
(B/2 cos R - A/2 sin R, B/2 sin R + A/2 cos R)
```

Comment: On the figure, R is negative.